# Media upload not working fine with meta box in custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a **custom post type** with a **custom image field** created with **meta boxes.**

When I upload an image, the media upload window of WordPress is displayed correctly and I can  upload a new image.

The problem is when I want to put an image of the media library because the images of the media library aren't loading.

The `code` I use to load the media uploader is the next:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".boton-imagen-caja").click(function() {
    formfieldID = jQuery(this).prev().attr("id");
    formfield = jQuery('#' + formfieldID).attr('name');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
  });
  var restore_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;
  window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    var imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
    jQuery('#' + formfieldID).val(imgurl);

    tb_remove(); 
    window.send_to_editor = restore_send_to_editor;
  }
});
</script>
```

**I put a screenshot of the problem:**

[Screenshot of the media upload window where the media library images aren't loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXDyy.jpg)

Comment: I still have the same problem. I have used this code other times and it worked fine. Could it be related to the wordpress version?